# How to count 5 level databases (childs+grandchilds+grand-grandchilds+grand-grand-grandchilds) of a specific parent using Realm in Swift?

Tags: swift, realm

I have a 5 databases setup like this Parent->Child->Grandchild->Grand-Grandchild->Grand-Grand-Grandchild, so far I could manage to count to the level 3 of a specific parent, but couldn't go deeper to 2 last levels.

```
class Parent : Object {
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
    let childs = List<Child>()
}
class Child : Object {
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
    let grandchilds = List<Grandchild>()
    var giveBirth = LinkingObjects(fromType: Parent.self, property: "childs")
}
class Grandchild : Object {
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
    var giveBirth = LinkingObjects(fromType: Child.self, property: "grandchilds")
}
class Grand-Grandchild : Object {
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
    var giveBirth = LinkingObjects(fromType: Grandchild.self, property: "grand-grandchilds")
}
class Grand-Grand-Grandchild : Object {
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
    var giveBirth = LinkingObjects(fromType: Grand-Grandchild, property: "grand-grand-grandchilds")
}
```

I used this line to count grandchilds:

```
if let parent = itemsFromParentList?[indexPath.row] {    
    parent.childs.flatMap { $0.grandchilds }.count + parent.childs.count
}
```

I'm stucking with a solution that can count all the child-items which belong to a specific parent (further the incurred childs databases when needed to grow).

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you need several object types? Why not the only object with `ancestors: [YourObject]` and `decendants: [YourObject]` properties?

Comment: You may want to alter the var names to reduce complexity. A parent has a child and the child has a child but a parent doesn't directly have a grandchild. The child of a child would be it's child, not it's grandchild. Of course the relationships are relative  so if you only care about how a grandChild is associated with the parents parent, this works. However, it seems you can simplify this diagram by re-using the same object that has my_parent property and a my_child property (or properties) and create a path from a parent to their child and from their child back to their parent (or parents)